# Pass additional options to GDAL in QGIS v3

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I'm using gdalwarp inside a QGis v3 model (using qgismodeler) and I'd like to pass the `-tap` option to the command.

I can't find where to place this. Is it possible to add additional options to gdal command